# How to get BroadcastReceiver for Action :android.intent.action.MAIN and android.intent.category.HOME in My Android Application

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

Every One

Can i Get BroadcastReceiver for This Intent when i press home Key :

```
       Starting activity: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN   cat=   [android.intent.category.HOME] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.htc.launcher/.Launcher }
```

I don't want to Consider com.htc.luncher as it will we different for Other Android Device .

Here i my Simple Class For BroadcastReceiver :

```
 public class HomeBrodcast extends BroadcastReceiver{

 @Override
 public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();


 }

}
```

In Manifest :

```
  <receiver android:name="xxx.yyy.zzz.sss.HomeBrodcast">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"></action>
            <categary android:name="android.intent.category.HOME"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

For Register BroadcastReceiver  in My Activity :

```
          mHomeBrodcast=new HomeBrodcast();
      IntentFilter mHomeFilter=new IntentFilter("android.intent.action.MAIN");
      mHomeFilter.addCategory("android.intent.category.HOME");
      registerReceiver(mHomeBrodcast, mHomeFilter);
```

Now Problem is When After Start My Application i press Home Button Press and My Log Show Me this Intent :

```
  12-27 14:01:11.230: I/ActivityManager(123): Starting activity: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.HOME] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.htc.launcher/.Launcher }
```

So My Goal is to get Receiver for This Intent But When i Debug i am not Getting Any Thing Some Thing Must me Wrong .What should be Problem in Getting This Intent BroadCast .

Comment: no yet not.But you can try by reading android logs.

Comment: It's not a broadcasting intent, you might not be able to receive it by BroadcastReceiver.

Answer (score 2):

spelling category right in the manifest should help :)

Comment: in fact I have the exact same code, with correct spelling, and my receiver never receive a thing

Answer (score 0):

I do not think you can get that functionality, see https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/fNTysSA8mWQ

Answer (score 0):

Android internally calls `startActivity` for starting the ACTION_MAIN registered component to start the launcher. Since you are registered with the receiver, It wont be get called unless it calls with `sendBroadast`. Hope it helps